# Given this cipher by a friend. STUMPED, any push in the right direction would be loved

Tags: cipher

```
       270EEbAD8FFh5A14Ca8293Dc4EF7Bf 
       F678EtAB21Dv4028A 1D56Dh3BD01c 
       7A54Fs51E3Bp94793x3E1E7g04A0Fc 
       86967s00CAFlDC235o2D740a6101Af 
       9B481 FF749zF889Fb6DDB4y9E7B3g 
       91921z6CC8FxA1B46 9EB00pA4237i 
       09054o55926b09CCC DE4EF 1EA83x 
       93664 E221Es9DF7Ae56FE5 BCE0C  
       2F0FCcA8BC1v2F174b2F336nBF022
```

I have tried a multitude of things, yet am stumped.

Comment: It would help if you described what you tried, and how it failed.

Comment: I'm on my phone, and not going to actually try any of this, so you get a comment instead: there are obviously two parts here, the lowercase letters and the blocks of hex digits. I'd start by separating them, and seeing if either makes any sense on its own. (Maybe the letters are a substitution cipher, or maybe the hex makes a pretty picture when converted to binary, stuff like that.)

Comment: Yes, based on @Bass's comment, are you sure this is a cipher?